# Flexbox. Расположение элементов

Tags: html, css

Нужно расположить форму таким образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я её расположил справа, но не могу элементы формы выравнить по центру.
Можете, пожалуйста, помочь в структуре html и стилях css, только начал верстать.

```css
head, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 72px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.logo {
  padding-left: 150px;
}

.navigation {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-right: 148px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.menu li {
  padding-left: 45px;
  color: #ffffff;
  list-style: none;
  opacity: 0.69;
}

.form_template {
 background-color: #9a9a9a;
 height: 713px;
 display: flex;
}

.inner {
 flex: 1 0 512px;
 flex-direction: column;
 max-width: 50%;
}

.logo1 {
 padding-left: 150px;
 padding-top: 105px;
}

.title {
    height: 70px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    padding-left: 150px;
    max-width: 100%;
}


.text {
 padding-left: 150px;
 padding-bottom: 45px;
    height: 61px;
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 23px;
    max-width: 70%;
}

.download {
 background: none;
 margin-left: 150px;
    width: 135px;
    height: 42px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.free_trial {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1 1 360px;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.trial {
 width: 360px;
    height: 54px;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.span {
 color: #ff8b38;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>AX IT</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="AXIT.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
 <!-- Header -->
 <header class="header">
   <div class="logo">
    <img src="img/Logo.png">
   </div>
   <nav class="navigation">
    <ul class="menu">
     <li>Features</li>
     <li>About</li>
     <li>Pricing</li>
     <li>Reviews</li>
     <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
 </header>
 <!-- Form -->
 <section class="form_template">
  <div class="inner">
      <div class="logo1">
       <img src="img/Logo1.png">
      </div>
   <div class="title">
    MODERN AXURE TEMPLATE
                FOR BEAUTIFUL PROTOTYPES
   </div>
   <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean
                euismod bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus
                accumsan et viverra justo commodo.
   </div>
   <button class="download">
    Download
   </button>
  </div>
   <form class="free_trial">
    <p class="trial">Try Your<span class="span">&nbsp;FREE&nbsp;</span>Trial Today</p>
    <input type="text" name="1">
    <input type="text" name="2">
    <input type="text" name="3">
    <button class="get_started">
     
    </button>
   </form>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не адаптировал ...**смотреть на весь экран**

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.item {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.name {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
}

.smal {
  color: orange;
}

.device {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.device:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
}

.voises {
  color: #777;
}

.button {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 6px 20px;
}

h4 {
  background: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.color {
  color: orange;
}

form {
  background: #fff;
  width: 280px;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}

form input {
  display: block;
  margin: 2px auto;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 250px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

[type="submit"] {
  padding: 6px 0;
  background: orange;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="name">
      <span class="bold">ax</span>
      <span class="smal">it</span>
    </div>
    <div class="device">
      Lorem ipsum dolor <br> sit amet consectetur
    </div>

    <p class="voises">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur<br> adipisicing elit. Sapiente delectus praesentium<br> eaque dicta autem quis cupiditate assumenda<br> pariatur enim error?
    </p>
    <a href="#" class="button">Download</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item_left">
    <form action="javascript()">
      <h4>Try your <span class="color">Free</span> Trial Today</h4>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
      <input type="submit" value="Get Started">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
head, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 72px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.logo {
  padding-left: 150px;
}

.navigation {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-right: 148px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.menu li {
  padding-left: 45px;
  color: #ffffff;
  list-style: none;
  opacity: 0.69;
}

.form_template {
 background-color: #9a9a9a;
 height: 713px;
 display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

.inner {
 flex: 1 0 512px;
 flex-direction: column;
 max-width: 50%;
}

.logo1 {
 padding-left: 150px;
 padding-top: 105px;
}

.title {
    height: 70px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    padding-left: 150px;
    max-width: 100%;
}


.text {
 padding-left: 150px;
 padding-bottom: 45px;
    height: 61px;
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 23px;
    max-width: 70%;
}

.download {
 background: none;
 margin-left: 150px;
    width: 135px;
    height: 42px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.free_trial {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1 1 360px;
    align-items: center;
}

.trial {
 width: 360px;
    height: 54px;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    justify-content: center;
}

.span {
 color: #ff8b38;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>AX IT</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="AXIT.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
 <!-- Header -->
 <header class="header">
   <div class="logo">
    <img src="img/Logo.png">
   </div>
   <nav class="navigation">
    <ul class="menu">
     <li>Features</li>
     <li>About</li>
     <li>Pricing</li>
     <li>Reviews</li>
     <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
 </header>
 <!-- Form -->
 <section class="form_template">
  <div class="inner">
      <div class="logo1">
       <img src="img/Logo1.png">
      </div>
   <div class="title">
    MODERN AXURE TEMPLATE
                FOR BEAUTIFUL PROTOTYPES
   </div>
   <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean
                euismod bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus
                accumsan et viverra justo commodo.
   </div>
   <button class="download">
    Download
   </button>
  </div>
   <form class="free_trial">
    <p class="trial">Try Your<span class="span">&nbsp;FREE&nbsp;</span>Trial Today</p>
    <input type="text" name="1">
    <input type="text" name="2">
    <input type="text" name="3">
    <button class="get_started">
     
    </button>
   </form>
 </section>
```